# Why does my footer disappear when I apply fixed positioning?

Tags: html, css

When I write the position fixed the footer disappears, and if I delete the `position:fixed` the footer comes back. Why is that?

```css
.footer2 {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 48px;
    background-color: #d6d6d6;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="index.html" id="logo"></a>
    </header>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <section class="layout2">

            <nav class="layout2_nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Layout 1</a></li>
                    <li class="selected"><a href="layout2.html">Layout 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="layout3.html">Layout 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <aside>
                <section class="flex-container-aside">
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                </section>
            </aside>
            <main>
                <section class="flex-container2 ">
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                </section>
            </main>
        </section>
    </div>

    <footer class="footer2">
    </footer>

</body>
```

Comment: It doesn't disappear. It has no size because fixed elements behave differently. Put something in it and it'll show up.

Comment: Set a width when using `fixed` or `absolute`

Answer (score 1):

just add `width` because when `div` has `position: fixed;` you must set width and height

```css
.footer2 {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 48px;
    width: 48px;
    background-color: #d6d6d6;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="index.html" id="logo"></a>
    </header>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <section class="layout2">

            <nav class="layout2_nav">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Layout 1</a></li>
                    <li class="selected"><a href="layout2.html">Layout 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="layout3.html">Layout 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <aside>
                <section class="flex-container-aside">
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                </section>
            </aside>
            <main>
                <section class="flex-container2 ">
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                    <div></div>
                </section>
            </main>
        </section>
    </div>

    <footer class="footer2">
    </footer>

</body>
```